# Unity2D local scale issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a 2d platformer and there are these enemies with a patrol system as so:

```
public TextMeshProUGUI m_Object;
public SpriteRenderer sp;
public Transform groundCheck;

bool isFacingRight = true;

RaycastHit2D hit;


private void Update()
{
    hit = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, -transform.up, 1f, groundLayers);

    
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(hit.collider != false)
    {
        if (isFacingRight)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
            
        }
        else
        {

           
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        sp.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, 1f, 1f);
        Debug.Log(transform.localScale.x);
        float placeholder = sp.transform.localScale.x;
        m_Object.transform.localScale = new Vector3(placeholder, 1f, 1f);
        Debug.Log(m_Object.transform.localScale.x);
    }
}
```

In the end part I am trying to flip the text so it stays facing the logical way however it is not working since when it hits the edge the text disappears and when it its the other edge the text comes back.

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: As long as the `Text` isn't a child of the `sp.transform` you don't need to flip the scale

Comment: Thanks for replying however the text isn't going to follow the enemy.

Comment: is the `Text` a text element or a `Sprite` with text on it?

Comment: it is a text mesh pro with a parent of a canvas and that is parented to the enemy.

Comment: You would be better off updating the `Text`s position while not parented to the enemy, see docs on how to convert the [WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)